# Magic traffic bot - what is it?

Tags: traffic

What is magic traffic bot ?
And what is it used for?

Comment: Where did you hear the phrase?

Comment: Yeah, where did you hear about it?  It definitely does not look legit to me.

Comment: If its too good to be true.....

Comment: Wonder if they took a leaf out of Apple's book when it came to deciding a name.

Answer (score 3):

[Looks like it spoofs traffic to your website.](http://www.magictrafficbot.com/)

Also looks suspicious.

Comment: Do you think it can improve stats of your website?

Comment: I think they want you to think that it will.  It looks REALLY suspicious to me and I would not get involved in it myself.

Answer (score 3):

No no...

MagicTrafficBot access a website, providing your URL as the referrer. What they want you to count on is that the webmaster of the target site seeing your URL in their referrer's list and clicking on it to see your site.

What this means is that the visitors that MTB will 'magically' get for you is going to be from angry webmasters who've seen their bandwidth, site traffic, and stats programs filled up with a bunch of fake hits and page views. Sure, they won't know right away that it's fake, but any webmaster worth his salt will be able to tell their numbers have been artificially inflated by a program, not real traffic.

The minute I see a bunch of hits with the same referrer, I'll check it out, sure. But, all the webmaster has to do is look at the times the hits came in. Thousands of hits with less than a second total duration, all within a few minutes. Blatantly obvious crap.

And this isn't even getting in to what it reports as the User Agent, OS, etc.

If any of my sites started getting traffic from this MTB crap, I'd be blocking IPs and then writing my own script that would inflate YOUR numbers, and get you back 10-fold :)